# Wireless connection connecting and disconnecting all the time

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, connection-sharing

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 on my laptop and I use a 3G USB modem for my Internet connection.

I wanted to share this Internet connection with my girlfriend's laptop that is running Window XP. Basically, I created the the wireless connection on my laptop and now it just connects and disconnects all the time. Why is it doing this? I am connected to the Internet via the 3G USB modem while I am also trying to connect the wireless set up, could that be the reason?

Is there anything I should do on the Windows computer during the wireless set up?

Comment: [Suspiciously sounds like this question at `askubuntu.com`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64494/wired-connection-shared-with-other-computers-connects-then-disconnects-in-11-10) only that they use a wired connection... Maybe this is still of help as it's `dnsmasq`-related.

Comment: That's great. Thanks. sudo killall dnsmasq and restarting dnsmasq made it work like a charm. Thank you. Now I am just looking, how I could make the other Window computer gets the connection.

Comment: [Maybe this helps, the Ubuntu community wiki on "Connection Sharing"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing)